# Making rightBarButtonItem bold

Tags: swift, uinavigationbar

I am trying to set up a navigation button to appear red and semibold. I managed to changed the color but I'm having trouble changing it to semibold:

```
navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Sign Up", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(signIn))
navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem?.tintColor = .red
UIBarItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes(
[
    NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 12, weight: .semibold)
],
for: .normal)
```

I tried rightBarButtonItem.appearance first but that doesn't seem to be an option.

I'm working with Swift 4.2.

Comment: What about setting the `style` to `.done`?

Comment: That worked. Thanks!

Comment: By "bold", do you mean you just want the button to match the appearance of the done button in iOS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the `style` property to `.done` to make the `UIBarButtonItem` bold. This will work until Apple changes how the done button looks in a newer version of iOS.

```
navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem?.style = .done
```

Answer (score 0):

Well to have fully customized bar button appearance, you can use bar button items with custom view just like this

```
    let doneButton: UIButton = UIButton (type: UIButton.ButtonType.custom)
    doneButton.setTitle("Done", for: .normal)
    doneButton.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 14)
    doneButton.setTitleColor(.blue, for: .normal)

    doneButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.doneBarButtonTapped(sender:)), for: UIControl.Event.touchUpInside)

    doneButton.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 30, height: 30)
    let barButton = UIBarButtonItem(customView: doneButton)

    navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = barButton
```